# PHP preg_match() - Regex to vague?

Tags: regex, class, preg-match

I have never really used regular expressions all that much and as such i have a few questions.

Basically i have built a simple class that returns text inbetween user specified tags.

```
function getData($tagname){
    $this->tagname = $tagname;
    $string = $this->dump;
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/s";
    preg_match($pattern,$string,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

This is giving me the info required but its returning multiple copies in the array, im just wondering what the reason behind this is?

For example

```
$depData->getData('departureTime');
```

Returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2012/03/07 12:45:13 [1] => 41 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2012/03/07 12:45:13 [1] => 56 ) )
```

Im thinking that its something to do with my regex being to vague?

Comment: Please paste the input you're matching against.

Comment: <departurePoint>Gorouck</departurePoint> <departureTime>2012/03/07 12:45:13</departureTime> <crew>3</crew> <passengers>85</passengers>

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this is not the actual result you're getting. You should be getting `<departureTime>2012/03/07 12:45:13</departureTime>` in `Array[0]` and `2012/03/07 12:45:13` in `Array[1]`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, the nested array comes from the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option that adds the match index. Remove that option and the result will be what you are expecting. I think the missing tags in the first results are a displaying problem, the index is the one of the opening tag.

Comment: @TimPietzcker if you mean the nested array, i know thats from the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag so thats fine. Its mainly just me trying to get my head around using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving giving you 2 results first is for the **whole expresion** `<tag>(.*?)</tag>` and the second result is for the result in the **parentheses** `(.*?)`

Also I created an example for you to see the difference between the first capture (whole expression) and the parentheses capture (your serach).

http://xrg.es/#1ompqhf

Note: I replaced `<` and `>` with `"` for you to see more clearly what's different.

Comment: As i said im not that clued up on regular expressions, how would i go about resolving this issue?

Comment: There's no issue.. you just need to grab the first result.. also.. if you don't care about where the expression was found.. remove the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` parameter.

Comment: +1 the resulting nested array was a bit irritating, but that comes from the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option that adds the match index!